# Entity table is not mapped

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpql

I'm new to Springboot and I'm having challenges retrieving an entry from my Entity table using JPQL statements.

I am running a small spring web project and a call from Postman to my Java API is supposed to return a "Tour" entity. The issue is that when I use a the `em.find(Entity.class, PrimaryKey)`, I have no problems retrieving the entity but when I use a JPQL statement `"SELECT t FROM tour t WHERE t.employee.empName = ?1"` It throws an exception basically saying that the entity table is not mapped.

Any suggestions as to how to overcome this?

Relevant code:
API method

```
@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
public ResponseEntity<Tour> testMethod(@RequestBody String name){

    Tour t = null;;
    try {
        t = service.getTour(name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Tour>(t, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Service method

```
public Tour getTour(String name) throws Exception{
    Tour t = dao.getTour(name);

    if(t == null) {
        throw new Exception("Service.TOUR_NOT_FOUND");
    }

    return t;
}
```

DAO method

```
public Tour getTour(String name) {
    String sql = "SELECT t FROM tour t WHERE t.employee.empName = ?1";
    Query q = em.createQuery(sql);
    q.setParameter(1, name);

    TourEntity te = (TourEntity) q.getSingleResult();

    Tour t = new Tour();
    Employee e = new Employee();
    ArrayList<Visitor> vl = new ArrayList<Visitor>();

    for(VisitorEntity ve : te.getVisitors()) {
        Visitor v = new Visitor();
        v.setVisitorId(ve.getId());
        v.setName(ve.getName());
        v.setEmail(ve.getEmail());
        v.setCompany(ve.getCompany());
        v.setFeedback(ve.getFeedback());
        v.setDesignation(ve.getDesignation());
        v.setPhoneNo(ve.getPhone());

        vl.add(v);
    }

    e.setEmpId(te.getEmployee().getEmpId());
    e.setName(te.getEmployee().getEmpName());
    e.setDesignation(te.getEmployee().getDesignation());
    if(te.getEmployee().getIsAdmin().equals("Y")) {
        e.setAdmin(true);
    }else {
        e.setAdmin(false);
    }
    e.setEmail(te.getEmployee().getEmail());
    e.setPassword(te.getEmployee().getPassword());

    t.setTourId(te.getId());
    t.setFeedback(te.getFeedback());    
    t.setVisitor(vl);
    t.setEmployee(e);
    t.setTourDate(te.getTourDate().toLocalDate());

    return t;
}
```

Entity classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tour")
public class TourEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @Column(name="tour_date")
    private Date tourDate;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
    private EmployeeEntity employee;
    private String feedback;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=VisitorEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private List<VisitorEntity> visitor;

**Getters & Setters**

@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class InfoscionEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="emp_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer empId;
    @Column(name="empname")
    private String empName;
    private String email;
    private String designation;
    private String password;
    @Column(name="isadmin")
    private String isAdmin;

**Getters and Setters**
```

Thank you.

Comment: `JPQL` translates the class name to the specified table name. It thinks `tour` would be a class name. Use `SELECT t FROM TourEntity t...`

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @XtremeBaumer, I found out that JPQL translates the Entity class name to the table name.

The query should be: `SELECT t FROM TourEntity WHERE....`